# Python request upload file - 413 request entity too large

Tags: python

I have the following script that allows me to upload files to bestream.tv.
This does not work for files above the 95MB. What change could make?

```
import requests
import re

sessionObj = requests.session()
sessionObj.post('http://bestream.tv/login.html', data={'loginUsername':'my_user', 'loginPassword':'my_pass', 'submitme':'1'})
filehandle = open('Diabolik Lovers - 12.mp4', 'rb')

resp = sessionObj.get('http://bestream.tv/account_home.html')

url_form = re.search('url: \'(http:\/\/.*)?\'', resp.text).group(1)
sessionid = re.search('_sessionid:\s\'(.*)?\', cTracker:', resp.text).group(1)
ctracker = re.search('cTracker:\s\'(.*)?\', maxChun', resp.text).group(1)

r = sessionObj.post(url_form, data={'_sessionid':sessionid, 'folderId':'', \
                    'cTracker':ctracker, 'maxChunkSize':'100000000'}, files={'files[]':(filehandle.name, filehandle)})

print(r.text)
```

This prints as a result:

```
413 Request Entity Too Largue
```

To upload the file from the web, I get these results in chrome -> Network:

```
Accept:application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Content-Disposition:attachment; filename="Diabolik%20Lovers%20-%206.5.mp4"
Content-Range:bytes 0-99999999/168152948
Content-Type:multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryHNdI5JvVzIVROkWQ
Origin:http://bestream.tv
Referer:http://bestream.tv/account_home.html
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.135 Safari/537.36


Accept:application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Content-Disposition:attachment; filename="Diabolik%20Lovers%20-%206.5.mp4"
Content-Range:bytes 100000000-168152947/168152948
Content-Type:multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryfsXuVqiBMXo1Vtn7
Origin:http://bestream.tv
Referer:http://bestream.tv/account_home.html
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.135 Safari/537.36
```

And so on until you finish uploading your file.

So I implied that it is rising every 100000000 bytes. What should I modify my script to do the same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error you are getting is the way of the web server telling you, that you can't, in fact, upload larger files. How big a request the server accepts is up to the server administrator, and not in any way in control of the client (your code).

*I assume, because the docs of `requests` don't explicitly tell:* Posting with `maxChunkSize` would allow a "chunked" HTTP transfer (see also: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding) which leaves *still* the file size intact, because the chunking is on another abstraction layer.

I'm afraid you'd have to slice the file yourself and POST each piece.

Comment: So I was looking at the code of the web and network behavior when uploading, the file is uploaded into pieces of what is defined 'maxChunkSize' '100000000'. How could I do to send the file into pieces?

Comment: I updated my answer. You probably mistook `maxChunkSize` for something it isn't.

Comment: I updated my question. I read the link you sent me, but I'm more lost than before, I do not know how to direct my problem.

Comment: Slice your file in pieces not bigger than what the web server accepts. Upload each one.

Comment: How do I can do, so that in the end an all pieces on the server?

Comment: That's a completely differen question. google 'python split files"

Comment: Thanks. Here is the solution:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30112916/python-as-i-can-upload-the-file-into-several-pieces-to-the-server/30137010#30137010