# Python - As I can upload the file into several pieces to the server?

Tags: python

Update the code:

```
import requests
import re

sessionObj = requests.session()
sessionObj.post('http://bestream.tv/login.html', data={'loginUsername':'my_user', 'loginPassword':'my_pass', 'submitme':'1'})
filehandle = open('Diabolik Lovers - 12.mp4', 'rb')

resp = sessionObj.get('http://bestream.tv/account_home.html')

url_form = re.search('url: \'(http:\/\/.*)?\'', resp.text).group(1)
sessionid = re.search('_sessionid:\s\'(.*)?\', cTracker:', resp.text).group(1)
ctracker = re.search('cTracker:\s\'(.*)?\', maxChun', resp.text).group(1)

tam=os.path.getsize('Diabolik Lovers - 12.mp4')

headers={}
n=0
stop=0

while stop < tam:
    start = n*100000000
    stop = min(start+99999999, tam)
    contentrange = 'bytes {}-{}/{}'.format(start, stop, tam)
    headers['Content-Range'] = contentrange
    filehandle.seek(start)
    r = sessionObj.post(url_form, headers=headers, files = {'files[]': (filehandle.name, filehandle)})
    n+=1
    print(r.text)
```

The answer given:

```
[{"name":"Diabolik Lovers - 6.5.mp4","size":68152948,"type":"","error":null}]
```

When uploading the file from the web, I get these results in Chrome -> Network:

```
Accept:application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Content-Disposition:attachment; filename="Diabolik%20Lovers%20-%206.5.mp4"
Content-Range:bytes 0-99999999/168152948
Content-Type:multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryHNdI5JvVzIVROkWQ
Origin:http://bestream.tv
Referer:http://bestream.tv/account_home.html
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.135 Safari/537.36


Accept:application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Content-Disposition:attachment; filename="Diabolik%20Lovers%20-%206.5.mp4"
Content-Range:bytes 100000000-168152947/168152948
Content-Type:multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryfsXuVqiBMXo1Vtn7
Origin:http://bestream.tv
Referer:http://bestream.tv/account_home.html
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.135 Safari/537.36
```

I need to upload the file into pieces larger than 100000000 bytes, how could modify the code to do so?

Comment: You _can_ explicitly craft range requests and upload a piece of a time, but you have to do so manually. But why do you want to? If you just want to (a) stream an upload, and possibly (b) resume an interrupted upload, ask that.

Comment: How i can explicitly craft range requests and upload a piece of a time? The server can upload files up to 100000000 bytes. From the website I can go up to 2GB, but I need to make a script for uploading files that work like the web.

Comment: `requests` doesn't really do anything to help you here. You have to understand the HTTP Content-Range specification, and how your particular server handles it, and write the headers and split up the file manually.

Comment: @pyCthon: No, that one doesn't have anything to do with sending partial requests with Content-Range headers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much research, finally I got it!

```
import requests
import os
import re


arc='Diabolik Lovers - 12.mp4'
sessionObj = requests.session()
sessionObj.post('http://bestream.tv/login.html', data={'loginUsername':'my_user', 'loginPassword':'my_pass', 'submitme':'1'})
filehandle = open(arc, 'rb')

resp = sessionObj.get('http://bestream.tv/account_home.html')

url_form = re.search('url: \'(http:\/\/.*)?\'', resp.text).group(1)

tam = os.path.getsize(arc)
l = 0
n = 0
headers={}

while l < tam:
    start = n*100000000
    if start+99999999 < tam:
        stop = min(start+99999999, tam)
    else:
        stop = tam-1
    contentrange = 'bytes {}-{}/{}'.format(start, stop, tam)
    headers['Content-Range'] = contentrange
    filehandle.seek(start)
    fi = 'file_%s' % n
    filehandle2 = open(fi, 'wb')
    f=filehandle.read(100000000)
    filehandle2.write(f)
    filehandle2.close()
    ff=open(fi, 'rb')
    r = sessionObj.post(url_form, headers=headers, files = {'files[]': (filehandle.name, ff)})
    ff.close()
    os.remove(fi)
    l+=len(f)
    n+=1
```

Answer (score 2):

At least as of version 2.7.0, `requests` doesn't do anything to help you use partial-content requests.

But it doesn't do anything to stand in your way, either. And it's not all that hard.

You do need to understand [RFC 7233](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7233), which describes how Range and Content-Range work. And the practical issues that many specific servers have (or at least any practical issues that your particular server has). But the basic idea is pretty simple:

For each 100000000 bytes, you send another request, with an extra header like this:

```
start = n*100000000
stop = min(start+99999999, filesize)
contentrange = 'bytes {}-{}/{}'.format(start, stop, filesize)
headers['Content-Range'] = contentrange
```

Then, of course, instead of sending the whole file, you send just bytes `start`-`stop` of the file. (You can do that by `open`ing the file then `seek`ing to `start`, or by `mmap`ping the file then sending a view-slice, or whatever else you like.)

Comment: I updated my question. Add:

tam=os.path.getsize('Diabolik Lovers - 12.mp4')

headers={}
n=0
stop=0

while stop < tam:
    start = n*100000000
    stop = min(start+99999999, tam)
    contentrange = 'bytes {}-{}/{}'.format(start, stop, tam)
    headers['Content-Range'] = contentrange
    filehandle.seek(start)
    r = sessionObj.post(url_form, headers=headers, files = {'files[]': (filehandle.name, filehandle)})
    n+=1
    print(r.text)

Comment: The answer given: [{"name":"Diabolik Lovers - 6.5.mp4","size":68152948,"type":"","error":null}]
Why do I get null?